# is it possible to change the time on a docker container

Tags: windows, docker

My docker container in windows is about 9 hours in the future and is preventing https from working.

I'm trying to make a SOAP call using C#. It all works perfectly on my Win10 WS, but if I put it into a docker container on the same host it fails with

> Exception thrown:
>   'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' in
>   mscorlib.dll An exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code An unsecured or
>   incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the
>   inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.

This is on a windows 10 machine (Ver 1803)

I have confirmed that both my host and the container have the same time zones (UTC+8) and if I alter my host time to try to compensate, then the host has the same error but the container doesnt seem to want to take the new time and remains about 9 hours in the future.

I found some similar issues from about a year ago, but none seem to have resolved the problem. Without a fix, I cant see how I can have this working inside a container.

I have tried it on the following images

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:20181113-4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803
FROM microsoft/iis
```

Running with Docker Desktop 2.1.0.1 (37199)

EDIT

I also tried using curl on windows to access a bank site (https) which also fails in the container but works fine on my workstation. The curl error is as follows

```
PS C:\> curl https://www.anz.com.au/personal/
curl : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl https://www.anz.com.au/personal/
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: 
(System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt
   pWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe
   ll.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

FURTHER INFO

Installing mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8 on windows server 2019 (ver 1809) the date follows the host correctly in the container and my IIS app can now communicate with the https site it needed.

It's looking like there may be a long standing issue with the 1803 version and dates. I'm still hoping someone out there will have a solution for the 1803 version.

Comment: `time 13:30:00` command will change the time in windows

Comment: Unfortunately that doesnt work in a container

Comment: It was only my thought I do not have used windows containers yet

Answer (score 2):

I have determined that the windows ver 1803 docker containers (probably not the host OS) has an issue with dates inside a docker container. I have updated my OS using windows update to 1903 and re-ran the 1803 version docker container and it still exhibits the same problem.

I then created a ver 1903 container, and this now correctly reflects the current date/time and not one thats about 9 hours in the future.

So in shor, the solution is to upgrade to a more recent Win10 version.